# How to put a transparent color mask on a 3D object in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I've been trying to 'submerge' a 3D object in a semi-transparent 3D plane of water (without the whole water plane showing), and after having experimented with custom blending modes for hours, I don't really get how to do it.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mglonnro/p2ju4qbk/34/

```
    var camera, scene, renderer, geometry, material, mesh,
      surface_geometry, surface_material, surface_mesh,
      bottom_geometry, bottom_material, bottom_mesh;
    
    init();
    animate();
    
    function init() {
    
      scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
      camera.position.set(0, 200, 500);
      camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
      scene.add(camera);
    
      geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200);
      material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
      mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      scene.add(mesh);
    
      bottom_geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(10000, 10000);
      bottom_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xFFAAAA,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide
      });
      bottom_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(bottom_geometry, bottom_material);
      bottom_mesh.rotation.set(Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
      bottom_mesh.position.set(0, -200, 0);
      scene.add(bottom_mesh);
    
      surface_geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(400, 400);
      surface_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x0000ff,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        transparent: true,
        opacity: 0.6
      });
    
      surface_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(surface_geometry, surface_material);
      surface_mesh.rotation.set(Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
      scene.add(surface_mesh);
    
      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    
    }
    
    function animate() {
    
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      render();
    
    }
    
    function render() {
    
      mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
      mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;
    
      renderer.render(scene, camera); 
    }
```

[image: Cube in water]

1. The cube is submerged, as it should be, and the parts covered by the transparent water look like I want them to look.
2. The problem, however, is that I want ONLY the cube and its submerged parts to be rendered, NOT the rest of the water plane.

**In other words:**

There are three objects in the scene:

- the redish "bottom" farthest away
- the cube, partly above, partly
  below the water
- the water

Is there some way to blend these together so that the water pixels are rendered only when they are on top of a cube pixel, not when they are just on top of the background/bottom?

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

1. Add stencil write functionality to the cube:

```
    const stencilId = 1;
    geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200);
    material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({
        stencilWrite: true,
        stencilFunc: THREE.AlwaysStencilFunc,
        stencilZPass: THREE.ReplaceStencilOp,
        stencilRef: stencilId
    });
```

2. Add stencil test functionality to the surface:

```
     surface_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x0000ff,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        transparent: true,
        opacity: 0.6,
        stencilWrite: true,
        stencilFunc: THREE.EqualStencilFunc,
        stencilRef: stencilId
      });
```

3. Realize that the three.js version in jsfiddle is too old to support stencils and move to [codepen](https://codepen.io/mikael-l-nnroth/pen/MWjLJyQ) :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stencil Test is a natural way to achieve that.

1. All objects which should have water on top of them write some stencil value.
2. Water plane has stencil test set to this value.

[three.js has stencil example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_clipping_stencil), but it uses IncrementWrap and DecrementWrap logic which is not needed for your case.

I recommend trying [ReplaceStencilOp](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/constants.js#L173) for cube and [EqualStencilFunc](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/constants.js#L182) for water.